# python 2.6.4 doesn't support mod_python?

Tags: python, django, mod-python

am looking for a way to run django by just using my xampp, and i bumped into this tutorial online
http://jyotirmaya.blogspot.com/2008/11/xampp-python-django.html
according to the author, mod_python 3.3.1 is not supported by python 2.6, but the blog post was created more then a year ago i think. is this thing still true until now? or its ok if I will use 2.6 and combine it with mod python 3.3.1 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mod_python must be compiled against the specific version of Python that the handler will be run in. At the time there was probably no Windows installer for mod_python built against 2.6.4, hence the hysteria.

In all fairness, you should probably be using [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) to run Django apps instead.

Comment: how will I use mod_wsgi ? I just downloaded it, and i think it should be placed under the apache modules folder coz the mod_wsgi file itself got a ".sO" extension, how will I load that module ?

Comment: You should refer to the install documentation available at the link. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnWindows

Comment: I ended up using the bitnami django stack installer,
here's the screenshot http://i45.tinypic.com/2heyp7q.jpg
then after installation, I saw the page says "it works" here's the screenshot http://i47.tinypic.com/35i65o5.jpg , but the problem now is I can't seem to find where the "test1" project that was automatically created during the installation process, the installer asked me to create an initial project and i named it "test1", but its missing under htdocs folder can you tell me where should django apps go ? here's the screenshot http://i45.tinypic.com/55qtft.jpg

Comment: i found it, its under my pc name folder

Comment: Unlike PHP scripts, WSGI applications are not required to be under the document root. In fact, it is recommended that they not be, since they are not processed by the web server directly.